# How to Use formula to insert Month to Date Automatically

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I want to use a single formula in cell A2 to insert Month to date Automatically. (in descending order).    Only show date within this month (September)

For example, Today is 9/2/2021.
It will show:
9/2/2021
9/1/2021

Let's say we entering the next day 9/3/2021.
It will show:
9/3/2021
9/2/2021
9/1/2021

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Rq7_yGZjXEqN84BIKmmZ0a8qlcPF2ZIgvdCD2aorGKc/edit?usp=sharing
Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in `A2` based on the date from `B1`:

```
=arrayformula(sort((eomonth(B1,-1))+(sequence(B1-eomonth(B1,-1),1)),1,0))
```

or this using `today()`:

```
=arrayformula(sort((eomonth(today(),-1))+(sequence(today()-eomonth(today(),-1),1)),1,0))
```